How to connect 20 same kind of tables in PowerBI?
I have excel workbook containing budget data on yearly basis. The budget is divided into certain categories and these categories are following a hierarchy. The columns of the sheets are as follows.
Forecast 2023-24, Actual 2023-24, Enterprise cost, Apr-23, May-23, ... , Mar-24
To create dashboard I have created few more sheets to normalize the actual budget sheet (Budget 2023-23 is divided into Level0, Level1, Level2). In these sheets, instead of separate columns of months, I have created single column containing year and another single column containing month. I followed the same approach for other years. For each year I have created a new workbook containing all the level sheets.
Example: Level0
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 Apr 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 May 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 Jun 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 Jul 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 Aug 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 Sep 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 Oct 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 Nov 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2023 Dec 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2024 Jan 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2024 Feb 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_1 2024 Mar 100$\n
Cat1 Cat2_2 2023 Apr 100$\n
...

Level1

Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 Apr 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 May 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 Jun 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 Jul 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 Aug 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 Sep 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 Oct 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 Nov 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2023 Dec 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2024 Jan 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2024 Feb 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_1 2024 Mar 100$\n
Cat2_1 Cat3_2 2023 Apr 100$\n
...

Likewise for other levels.
Note: Type of year and month column is text (cannot convert it to date as it is generating error).
I tried to connect them and create dashboard but it is not updating on selection of slicer as I want.
Let me know if you require any other information for clarification.
How can I add date table and connect it to all the level sheets so that I can add slicer for fiscal year and based on that my dashboard updates? Is my approach correct? What is the best way to create dashboard for these datasheets?

can you please add sample data and your expected output?

Sounds like you should ingest the data into PowerQuery first, do whatever transformations needed (like appending all the tables into one table). Then from there load into the DataModel. Have a look at About Power Query in Excel to get you started. After having a go, feel free to share a sample workbook with dummy data and post a link here (via OneDrive, Google Drive, DropBox etc...)

It got resolved by creating different sheets for each level of hierarchy. Thanks for the tip.
